# Implement dictionary using Java

Tags: java, dictionary

Task
Dictionary ADT

- The dictionary ADT models a searchable collection of key-element entries
- Multiple items with the same key are allowed
- Applications: word-definition pairs

Dictionary ADT methods:

- find(k): if the dictionary has an entry with key k, returns it, else, returns null
- findAll(k): returns an iterator of all entries with key k
- insert(k, o): inserts and returns the entry (k, o)
- remove(e): remove the entry e from the dictionary
- size(), isEmpty()

Operation Output Dictionary

```
insert(5,A) (5,A) (5,A)
insert(7,B) (7,B) (5,A),(7,B)
insert(2,C) (2,C) (5,A),(7,B),(2,C)
insert(8,D) (8,D) (5,A),(7,B),(2,C),(8,D)
insert(2,E) (2,E) (5,A),(7,B),(2,C),(8,D),(2,E)
find(7) (7,B) (5,A),(7,B),(2,C),(8,D),(2,E)
find(4) null (5,A),(7,B),(2,C),(8,D),(2,E)
find(2) (2,C) (5,A),(7,B),(2,C),(8,D),(2,E)
findAll(2) (2,C),(2,E) (5,A),(7,B),(2,C),(8,D),(2,E)
size() 5 (5,A),(7,B),(2,C),(8,D),(2,E)
remove(find(5)) (5,A) (7,B),(2,C),(8,D),(2,E)
find(5) null (7,B),(2,C),(8,D),(2,E)
```

Detailed explanation: NO

Comment: homework? Share your ideas/code - we'll try to help you if you have any specific problems.

Comment: I really like the way the problem is posed.

Comment: @marcog: Yeah, this one is hilarious. :D

Comment: What have you tried so far?  What did or didn't work?  Are you allowed to use built-in collections classes?

Answer (score 5):

Java already has a collection, which has almost all you need. You just need to add maybe one method. For starters explore java.util.Collection... classes. Then extend one to add required methods. If done properly, it's just a matter of few dozens lines.

For me, the easiest way to go is with `Map<Object, Set<Object>>`. The tricky thing is to return an iterator.

EDIT:

On the other hand I'd go with this `Entry.java`:

```
public class Entry<K, V> {

    K key;
    V value;

    public Entry(K key, V value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public K key() {
        return key;
    }

    public V value() {
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "(" + key + ", " + value + ")";
    }

    // Methods needed to correctly behave in containers like sets, hashmaps:
    // (I generated those automatically in NetBeans)
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        final Entry<K, V> other = (Entry<K, V>) obj;
        if (this.key != other.key && (this.key == null || !this.key.equals(other.key)))
            return false;
        if (this.value != other.value && (this.value == null || !this.value.equals(other.value)))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 7;
        hash = 23 * hash + (this.key != null ? this.key.hashCode() : 0);
        hash = 23 * hash + (this.value != null ? this.value.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }
}
```

... also with this: `Dictionary.java`

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class Dictionary<K, V> {

    private List<Entry<K, V>> set;

    public Dictionary() {
        this.set = new LinkedList<Entry<K, V>>();
    }

    /**
     * find(k): if the dictionary has an entry with key k, returns it, else, returns null
     */
    public Entry<K, V> find(K key) {
        // for all entries in set...
        //   check if key mathches
        //     - if it does than return it

        // else
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * findAll(k): returns an iterator of all entries with key k
     * @return
     */
    public Iterator<Entry<K, V>> findAll(K key) {
        // make a temporary list
        // for all entries in set...
        //   check if key matches
        //     - if it does than add it to temporary list

        // return the temporary list iterator (list.iterator())
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * insert(k, o): inserts and returns the entry (k, o)
     */
    public Entry<K, V> insert(K key, V value) {
        // obvious
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * remove(e): remove the entry e from the dictionary
     */
    public Entry<K, V> remove(Entry<K, V> entry) {
        return entry;
    }

    public int size() {
        return set.size();
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return size() == 0;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return set.toString();
    }
}
```

..., and this `DictionaryTest.java`:

```
public class DictionaryTest {

    static Dictionary<Integer, Character> dict = new Dictionary<Integer, Character>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        /*

        Test cases:

        1. insert(5,A) (5,A) (5,A)
        2. insert(7,B) (7,B) (5,A),(7,B)
        3. insert(2,C) (2,C) (5,A),(7,B),(2,C)
        4. insert(8,D) (8,D) (5,A),(7,B),(2,C),(8,D)
        5. insert(2,E) (2,E) (5,A),(7,B),(2,C),(8,D),(2,E)
        6. find(7) (7,B) (5,A),(7,B),(2,C),(8,D),(2,E)
        7. find(4) null (5,A),(7,B),(2,C),(8,D),(2,E)
        8. find(2) (2,C) (5,A),(7,B),(2,C),(8,D),(2,E)
        9. findAll(2) (2,C),(2,E) (5,A),(7,B),(2,C),(8,D),(2,E)
        10. size() 5 (5,A),(7,B),(2,C),(8,D),(2,E)
        11. remove(find(5)) (5,A) (7,B),(2,C),(8,D),(2,E)
        12. find(5) null (7,B),(2,C),(8,D),(2,E)
         */

        // Test case #1:
        test("insert(5,A)", dict.insert(5, 'A'));

        // Test case #2:
        test("insert(7,B)", dict.insert(7, 'B'));

        // Test case #3:
        test("insert(2,C)", dict.insert(2, 'C'));

        // ...

        // Test case #6:
        test("find(7))", dict.find(7));

        // implement all and check them during implementation


    }

    private static void test(String string, Object result) {
        System.out.print(string + " ");
        System.out.print(result);
        System.out.println(" " + dict);
    }
}
```

Comment: I really tried everything but i cant solve this ... i got 10 hours left 2 do this... Thanks for your comment though

Comment: Thanks alot for your help guys this really worked  :)
Thumbs up
Rekin   I love you

Comment: Guys i woderning is it possible 2 link this code with Gui code +
database(such as .read .write) to be able 2 load save etc

Comment: Hah, You are shooting yourself in the foot with such ambitions. You'll be fed up with database and GUI programming - trust me. Stick to what you need to do. If you want any interface, than make a command line. About the database - that's an overkill.

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest read up Hash tables with separate chaining. Hash tables is a good way to implement dictionaries. There are MIT lectures in the open course ware for this.See this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table for more details

Comment: Let me know if you need C# code for implementing hash tables :)